# PowerBuilder: how can i improve retrieve operation of datawindow

Tags: powerbuilder

my application is connnected to oracle 10g .as number of rows to be fetched are very large so lots of time get consumed in fetching .How can i improve fetch operation of datawindow. while searching, I found some "block" parameter to be set in database profile but not sure in it.

Answer (score 2):

First,determine if you really need all those rows retrieved to the client.  If the process is something like "Retrieve everything, then do some client-side calculation across the retrieved rows", I would think about doing all this processing in a stored procedure on the server.

You can look into shared objects, and perform the retrieval in a background thread.

Limit the number of columns retrieved to just those you really need.  "Select * from table" is ALWAYS a bad idea...

"Retrieve as Needed" might help, but that's only if the user is "paging" through the rows online.  If it's a large report, then this option doesn't gain you any advantage.

Ultimately, whenever there are a "large number of rows retrieved", you really should sit down and ask whether all this data needs to come down into the client app at all.

-Paul Horan-

Answer (score 0):

**Asynchronous Retrieval**

If you must retrieve so many rows is to set your database operation to asynchronous via the dbparm property. The only thing this does is frees up the GUI giving the illusion of better performance. The one thing that async will not help is the time between sending the query and first row returned, the GUI will be locked (hourglass) until the first row has been retrieved and after that async will allow the GUI to be non-hourglass. With async though you may have transaction challenges elsewhere so consider using a different transaction object.

**No code in datawindow object sqlpreview event**

Never put code, not even a comment in the sqlpreview unless absolutely necessary because it runs once for each row and can slow retrieval dramatically when retrieving a lot of rows.

**Cache drop-down-datawindow data or any semi-static data if possible**

If you have drop down datawindow's with a lot of rows it can affect performance a lot especially with a lot of rows. If the data is static you could cache it in memory and then manually assign the data to the drop down datawindow using the datawindow getChild function in combination with shareData function.

**Retrieve the data in delimited format**

This suggestion is really 'out there' beyond the normal paradigm of PowerBuilder programming, or any programming for that matter. If the data and interface allows you could potentially use a stored procedure which returns the data in a big chunk, essentially delimited data for which you will import the rows into the datawindow. This is something I have never seen done in my 15 years of PB programming but it could work for a few circumstances. There's a lot of communication overhead when retrieving a lot of rows so this minimizes that overhead in favor of server brute force power/speed and fast import rows functions.

I agree with Paul's answer especially limiting the number of columns as it could reduce the size of the retrieve considerably. Blocking size settings might help performance but probably not much.